# Mutual Information in a Binary Erasure Channel

Tags: information-theory

Imagine a Binary Erasure Channel as depicted on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_erasure_channel).

One equation describing the mutual information is:

$$
\begin{align*}I(x;y) 
 &= H(x) - H(x|y) \\
 &= H(x) - p(y=0) \cdot 0 - p(y=?) \cdot H(x) -p(y=1)\cdot 0\end{align*}$$

Why is it "$p(y=?) \cdot H(x)$" and not "$p(y=?) \cdot H(x|y=?)$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y = ?$ then $H(x) = H(x|y=?)$ since $y = ?$ gives you no information about $x$.

Comment: I see, is that because p(x=0|y=?)=p(x=1|y=?) in a BEC?

Comment: @user38931 The identity $H(x|y=?) = H(x)$ would be true even if $x$ were skewed. What we need is $p(x=0|y=?) = p(x=0)$.